# Implementing session state management for large data

Tags: javascript, asp.net, session, caching, viewstate

I have a asp.net web application
- one of the forms in it - is for entering records in a batch and then submitting the entire batch, so that it is saved to the database.
- to implement this there are 5 text-boxes and one grid-view - once you fill the fields and click 'add' button - the records gets added to the 'grid'. this step is repeated 50 times
- once there are 50 records in the grid... the 'post' button' is clicked so that the entire batch gets submitted to the Database.

there are 2 issues that I am aiming to resolve with the single implimentation
1 - sometimes the user's session terminates and they are kicked off from the system (they are middle of adding entries to the batch and have not saved the batch yet)  and are forced to log back in - and when they do all the entries they have entered are gone - all the fields and the grid-view are blank.
2 - sometimes the page refreshes and the same thing happens (the only difference is they don't have to re-log in)

- I am not trying to resolved the problem - however what I want to do is when any of the above two situation happens - the users should not have to renter say all the entries they have made to the batch - so what is the best way to impliment session state management in this situation - I know its a large amount of data so probably (Cache and saving it to a local file using java scripts) are the options
- My question is which technology to use and a brief overview of how to use it... you help is much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Look at [HTML 5 local storage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html) option.

Comment: If it fits in 4k you could put it all in a cookie...  50*20*5 sounds pretty close to that.  These fields more or less than 20 characters?  (You could always use more than one too...  50 per domain)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at Session-State Modes

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586.aspx Here are the options

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317604 Here is the configuration